# Value at risk under Student-$t$, skew Student-$t$ and Generalized error distribution

Tags: garch, risk, volatility-forecasting

I'm trying to calculate Value-at-risk (VaR) in the context of GARCH models. VaR is defined as the minimum potential loss that a portofolio may suffer in the $x\%$ worst cases over a given horizon.

My sample consists of S&P500 from 1996-01-03 to 2016-02-25.

I use several distributional assumptions for the standarized innovations of the GARCH process, e.g. Gaussian-GARCH, std-GARCH, sstd-GARCH and GED-GARCH.

My purpose is then to compare the forecast ability of the different GARCH specifications. The comparison should be based on the number of violations during forecast period.

I read some books and papers but still found some problems on how to compute the VaR under non-Gaussian assumptions. In the code below I specified a Gaussian GARCH model and than using `ugarchroll` function I forecast volatility over the next 500 days. Now I would need to check the goodness of the forecast. I can do that measuring the daily VaR on the out-of-sample forecasts and then compare it with the realized, i.e. historical, values.

```
mo1 <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list("sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1)), 
              mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1,1), include.mean = TRUE), 
              distribution.model = "norm")
 mo1rol <- ugarchroll(mo1, rend, n.ahead = 1, forecast.length = 500, refit.every = 50, refit.window = "moving", 
                 fit.control = list(), calculate.VaR = TRUE, VaR.alpha = c(0.01,0.05))
  VaR <- mo1rol@forecast$VaR[,"alpha(1%)"]
     return <- mo1rol@forecast$VaR[,"realized"]
  hit <- return < VaR
  sum(hit)
```

**Questions:**

1. Is that procedure correct?
2. What I should change to estimate the VaR under the other distributional assumptions mentioned above?
3. In the "rugarch" package the fuction `report` gives back the number of times tha VaR is violated and the result of Kupiec test and Christoffersen test (1998). Is that output enough to get the answer I need?

Comment: Consider describing exactly what the code does, that will make it easier for the audience. Also, VaR is a finance-specific term not known to general statistical audience. Hence, consider briefly introducing VaR as well.

Comment: sure! In the code written above I specified a GARCH model and than using ugarchroll function I forecast volatility over the next 500 days. Now I would need to check the goodness of the forecast. I can do that measuring the daily VaR on the out-of-sample forecasts and then compare it with the realized, i.e. historical, values. VaR is defined as the minimum potential loss that a portofolio may suffer in the x% worst cases over a given horizon.

Comment: It would be even better if you included this information by editing your post as not everyone reads the comments.

Comment: I tried to edit your question (especially the structure) to make it clearer; it might still not be perfect but I hope it is more easily comprehensible now. I hope I did not distort the meaning in the process.

Comment: I think the question as currently formulated would better fit the Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange (beta). I have flagged it accordingly. However, if you stripped all the details and just asked two separate questions (in separate posts), "How do I get VaR for a given distribution?" and "What is the conditional distribution of $\varepsilon_t$ at a specific time point $t$ if it follows a GARCH(1,1) process with std/sstd/GED standardized errors?" (or whatever other concrete statistical questions you have), that would be more relevant for the audience of Cross Validated.